# KubeFlow, handling large dynamic arrays and ParallelFor with current size limitations

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow, argo-workflows, argoproj

I've been struggling to find a good solution for this manner for the past day and would like to hear your thoughts.

I have a pipeline which receives a large & dynamic JSON array (containing only stringified objects), 
I need to be able to create a ContainerOp for each entry in that array (using dsl.ParallelFor).

This works fine for small inputs.

Right now the array comes in as a file http url due to pipeline  input arguements size limitations of argo and Kubernetes (or that is what I understood from the current open issues), but - when I try to read the file from one Op to use as input for the ParallelFor I encounter the output size limitation.

What would be a good & reusable solution for such a scenario?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> the array comes in as a file http url due to pipeline input arguements size limitations of argo and Kubernetes

Usually the external data is first imported into the pipeline (downloaded and output). Then the components use `inputPath` and `outputPath` to pass big data pieces as files.
The size limitation only applies for the data that you consume as value instead of file using `inputValue`.

The loops consume the data by value, so the size limit applies to them.

What you can do is make this data smaller. For example if your data is a JSON list of big objects `[{obj1}, {obj2}, ... , {objN}]`, you can transform it to list of indexes `[1, 2, ... , N]`, pass that list to the loop and then inside the loop you can have a component that uses the index and the data to select a single piece to work on `N` ->`{objN}`.